# Delphi 7: how to check if Windows themes is enabled?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7

Using Delphi 7, how can I check if Windows has a theme enabled (i.e. is it the classic gray windows look or not)?

Comment: Are you interested in whether the user has enabled themes system wide, or do you want to know the information for the current app? In order to give the best possible answer I think you should tell us what you plan to do with the information.

Comment: @David system-wide, sorry if that wasn't clear. `IsThemeActive` seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: It wasn't that it wasn't clear. That's what you asked. But I did wonder whether or not that was what you really wanted. It's unusual to ask for the system wide property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the unit `UxTheme.pas` and call the `IsThemeActive` function.

Delphi 7 was the first version that shipped with it but it should be possible to use that unit in older versions aswell as it is open source (written by Mike Lischke originally) that just uses WinAPI.

Comment: or IsAppThemed which UseThemes queries. They seem to behave identical, unless maybe you disable theming yourself.

Comment: Which happens if you don't have a manifest in your application or disable runtime themes. He asked if Windows has a theme enabled and not if the application has it enabled.

Comment: That's not correct, they behave identical without a manifest. D7 does not have runtime themes anyway.

Comment: @Sertac http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/26/10168421.aspx  And yes, D7 does have runtime themes. That was the version where Borland absorbed Mike Lischke's code.

Comment: @David - I wonder what does the api report to IsThemeActive if your application is forced by the OS to run withouth themes. edit: You are correct. Tested, two are different in that regard.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz It returns `True`.

Comment: @David - That's what makes the application to have a manifest. There's no runtime themes in the project options in D7. Notice the or in Stefan's comment.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz You typically add the `XPManifest` unit to your project. Or just link the comctl32 v6 manifest. The former just does the latter.

Comment: @David - I know. So what? You either have a manifest or not. There's no runtime themes functionality other than that. Mentioning both like they are separate options is meaningless.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I guess I don't understand the point you are making. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You've to use **uxtheme.dll**. I use [this](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1639) code in Delphi 5 and it works for me.

Comment: -1 for an answer that provides no detail. An offsite link is not enough. If you put the detail here then I can remove the down vote.

Comment: The linked code is very simple. So should I copy/paste it?

Comment: Probably not worth it because Stefan is right, this is built in to D7

Comment: You don't have to provide all the code. Most of the code is unremarkable anyway. Adding just three words makes this a better answer: "I use this code *to call IsThemeActive* in Delphi 5 …."